# Javascript this keyword refer to another object

Tags: javascript, this

I have this script:

```
Bla = function() {
  this.prop = 123;
}
Bla.prototype.yay = function() {
  console.log(this,this.prop);
}
X = new Bla();

$(document).ready(X.yay); // output: #document undefined --> why?
$(document).ready(function(){
  X.yay(); // output: Bla 123 --> desired result
});
```

How to make the first one calls correctly (`this` should refer to X) without extending `Object` ?

Comment: What do you mean, "*without extending `Object`*"?

Comment: without adding `Object.prototype.bla`

Comment: Uh, I don't think there even is a working solution that uses `Object.prototype`…

Comment: If I'm not forgotten, there is `Object.prototype.bind` from `ImpactJS` library (I ask because I forgot the `bind` function's name)

Comment: I've never heard of ImpactJS, but what you remember is the [`Function.prototype.bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) - that is native and does not need any extensions on `Object`.

Comment: ah yeah, that one http://impactjs.com/forums/impact-engine/bug-in-function-bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no matter where a function is called, `this` refers to object it is a property of, or the global object is not a property of an object.

When you pass the method into a function, that function is no longer a method of an object, but a local variable to the function, in which, in this case anyway, `this` refers to the `document` object, since that is the object the document ready event is called on.

In modern JavaScript implementations, you can [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the method to the object.

**Example:**

```
$(document).ready(X.yay.bind(X));
```

Note that this requires IE9 or better. The anonymous function you use is also an acceptable solution, and will work in older versions of IE.

Comment: Except `this` did not refer to the global object, but `document`?

Comment: @Bergi Good catch! That makes sense. I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bind`:

```
$(document).ready(X.yay.bind(X));
```

This creates a "wrapper" around the function that sets `this` to `X` when it is invoked.